# how can i show inputfields only on buttonclick with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i need to hide the inputfields of editing until the button edit is clicked then i want to show the input fields.
it has to toggle on click to show the inputfield.

I also wanted to change text of edit to close fields if the inputs are showing.

here is my code

```
<div class="personInfo">
          <h3>name <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-show="edit"></h3>
          <h3>email: <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" ng-show="edit"></h3>
          <h3>birthday: <input type="text" ng-model="user.birthday" ng-show="edit"></h3>
          <h3>password: <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="hidden" ng-show="edit"></h3>
          <button type="submit" class="save-button">Save</button>
          <button ng-click="edit">edit</button>
        </div>
```

ps: i tried to put edit in the ng-click to show only when edit is clicked but it is not working

Comment: `ng-click="edit = true"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button ng-click="edit = !edit">{{ edit ? 'close' : 'edit' }}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like

```
<div class="personInfo">
  <h3>name <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-show="IsEditMode"></h3>
  <h3>email: <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" ng-show="IsEditMode"></h3>
  <h3>birthday: <input type="text" ng-model="user.birthday" ng-show="IsEditMode"></h3>
  <h3>password: <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="hidden" ng-show="IsEditMode"></h3>
  <button type="submit" class="save-button">Save</button>
  <button ng-click="edit" ng-click="setMode(IsEditMode)">edit</button>
</div>
```

In your controller, create a property like

```
$scope.IsEditMode = false;
```

and then create an ng-click for your button like

```
//toggle function
$scope.setMode = function(mode)
{
   if(mode == true)
        $scope.IsEditMode = false;
   else
        $scope.IsEditMode = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a function to your `ng-click` call, like so: `ng-click="enable()"`. The function `enable()` can change the edit variable to true, and the fields will show.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a function, you can do it directly using: `ng-click="edit = !edit"`